# JPA CrudRepository for findIn method

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

In one requirement I need find in a list by id. Below is the example.

```
class Employee{
   Long id;
   Contractor contractor;
}
class Contractor {
   Long id;
   List<Address> addressList;
}
class Address {
   Long id;
   String line;
}
```

Now in EmployeeController.java class I need to find out by employee Id and address Id.

I have CrudRepository as below.

```
interface EmployeeRepository extends CrudRepository<Employee, Long> {
   Employee findOne(Long id);

   // I want one method here that can find by employee id and address id.
   Employee findByIdAndAddress(); 
}
```

When I try to run the spring application up it gives the below exception.

**PropertyReferenceException: No property Address found for type Employee!**

Thank you!

Comment: How can you find employee by address if there is no mapping defined between employee and address?

Comment: I guess the intention is to find an `Employee` for which there's a `Contractor` that in turn has a matching `Address`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the exception itself is quite clear, it tries to find a property "address" on `Employee`, which does not exist, so you'll have to join `Contractor` and `Address` to make that work. However, as far as I can see in the list of [reserved keywords](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.3.4.RELEASE/reference/html/repository-query-keywords.html), you can't do that with method naming.

So the solution is to write your own query, for example:

```
@Query("SELECT e FROM Employee e JOIN e.contractorList c JOIN c.addressList a " +
       "WHERE e.id = :id AND a.id = :addressId")
Employee findByIdAndAddress(@Param("id") Long id, @Param("addressId") Long addressId);
```